# Bash command to backfill Hive table—running multiple Hive commands with changing date variables

Tags: bash, hadoop, hive

Trying to figure out a way to backfill partitions of a ds partitioned Hive table.

I know how to run a Hive command from CLI, e.g.

```
$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive -e 'select a.col from tab1 a'
```

What I would like to do is provide a .txt file of different DS and have a new job run for each of those DS's, e.g.

```
    $HIVE_HOME/bin/hive -e 'INSERT OVERWRITE PARTITION ds = $DS_VARIABLE_HERE 
                            select a.col from tab1 a where ds = $DS_VARIABLE_HERE'
```

But I'm not so sure how to do this

I'm thinking of trying out

```
cat date_file.txt | hive -e 'query here'
```

But I'm not sure how to place the variable from the date_file file into the Hive query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to use shell command to iterate through the values:

Option 1:

> If you have fixed set of values you want to iterate through then

```
DS_VARIABLE_HERE=('val1' 'val2' 'val3')

for ((i=0;i<${#DS_VARIABLE_HERE[@]};i++))
do
$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive -e "INSERT OVERWRITE PARTITION ds = ${DS_VARIABLE_HERE[$i]} select a.col from tab1 a where ds = ${DS_VARIABLE_HERE[$i]}"
done
```

Option 2:

> if you want to iterate through lets say 1 to 10

```
for ((i=1;i<=10;i++))
do
$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive -e "INSERT OVERWRITE PARTITION ds = ${i} select a.col from tab1 a where ds = ${i}"
done
```

Comment: Since u want the values in .txt file. just use option 1. put the following part of code in .txt file :

DS_VARIABLE_HERE=('val1' 'val2' 'val3')

and in the shell script use "source file.txt"

Comment: The for ((i = ...) option, it would be difficult if the numbers aren't 0 padded